# Multiply two array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an two array like this:

```
$wij = array(0.25, 0.30, 0.25. 0.15, 0.5);

$nij = array(
array(3, 3, 2, 1, 2),
array(2, 2, 3, 2, 1),
array(1, 3, 2, 2, 1));

$rij = array();
```

I want to multiplying a value from **wij** array-variable into each **nij** array and join the result into **rij** array-variable, because `$nij` array always have more than 3 array than from the example. I dont have any clue just using for-loops in 1 looping. Please give me an example

Comment: What do you mean "join the result into rij" ? Do you mean you want to add the result to $rij array?

Answer (score 0):

if you want just add the values to $rij array use the code below:

```
$wij = array(0.25, 0.30, 0.25, 0.15, 0.5);

$nij = array( array(3, 3, 2, 1, 2), array(2, 2, 3, 2, 1), array(1, 3, 2, 2, 1));

$rij = array();


foreach($nij as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        foreach($wij as $multiplier) {
            $rij[] = $val * $multiplier;
        }
    }

}

print_r($rij);
```